# R Scripting on google sheets

Tags: r, scripting, rstudio, rscript

I have a google sheet which looks like this

```
Name  Surname  Country  Path
John   Snow      UK     /Home/drive/John 
BOB    Anderson  USA    /Home/drive/BOB
Tim    David     UK     /Home/drive/Tim 
Wayne  Green     UK     /Home/drive/Wayne
```

I have written a script which first checks if `country =="UK"`, if true, changes Path from `"/Home/drive/"` to `"/Server/files/"` using `gsub` in R.

Script

```
Pattern<-"/Home/drive/"

Replacement<- "/Server/files/"

gs_catalog_Staging <- apply(gs_catalog$Sheet_Name[4],function(x){
ifelse(gs_catalog$Sheet_Name[3]== "UK", gsub(Pattern,Replacement, gs_catalog$Sheet_Name[4],ignore.case=T),gs_catalog) })
```

The output i get (i put only the first row to save space):

```
Name  Surname  Country  Path
John   Snow      UK     c("/Server/files/John"), c("/Server/files/BOB"), c("/Server/files/BOB"),c("/Server/files/Tim"), c("/Server/files/Wayne")
```

The output I want

```
Name  Surname  Country  Path
John   Snow      UK     /Server/files/John
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Pattern<-"/Home/drive/"

Replacement<- "/Server/files/"

gs_catalog <- read.table(text = "Name  Surname  Country  Path
John   Snow      UK     /Home/drive/John 
BOB    Anderson  USA    /Home/drive/BOB
Tim    David     UK     /Home/drive/Tim 
Wayne  Green     UK     /Home/drive/Wayne", 
                         header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE
)

gs_catalog$Path <- ifelse(gs_catalog$Country == 'UK',
                          sub(Pattern, Replacement, gs_catalog$Path),
                          gs_catalog$Path
)
```

Results:

```
> gs_catalog
   Name  Surname Country                Path
1  John     Snow      UK  /Server/files/John
2   BOB Anderson     USA     /Home/drive/BOB
3   Tim    David      UK   /Server/files/Tim
4 Wayne    Green      UK /Server/files/Wayne
```